# Vector will not copy into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, vector

Still learning the ropes on C++.

I am importing a CSV file into a vector< vector >, changing that into an array of arrays, and then creating a Mat (an openCV data type) for training in an SVM.

I have the vectors building properly but I am having issues turning the vectors into arrays and I am getting this error:
*cannot convert 'std::vector' to 'double' in assignment*

For some reason the first copy statement is giving this error while the copy statement in the loop is working fine.

```
vector< vector<double> > labelsVec;
vector< vector<double> > trainingDataVec;
read_csv(infile1, labelsVec);
read_csv(infile2, trainingDataVec);
double labels[178] = {0.0};
double trainingData[178][5] = {0.0};

copy(labelsVec.begin(), labelsVec.end(), labels);

for (int row = 0; row < trainingDataVec.size(); ++row) {
  copy(trainingDataVec[row].begin(), trainingDataVec[row].end(), trainingData[row]);
}

Mat labelsMat(178, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);
Mat trainDataMat(178, 5, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to insert an array of doubles into a vector of a vector of doubles.

Comment: I think you want `vector<double> labelsVec;` as `labels` only has one dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy a `vector<double>` to a `double*` unless in very specific circumstances. The standard guarantees that vector elements are stored in contiguous memory so you basically can use the address of the first element of your `vector<T>` as an array of `T*`. C++11 already gives you this facility through `data()` method.

I never used OpenCV so I don't know if it requires the whole data matrix to be contiguous so I'm not actually sure this solution is applicable to your problem.

This of course doesn't directly apply to bidimensional data but you can easily use a workaround by filling an array just for the first dimension, take a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/emAz5i):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void foo(double** data, size_t i, size_t j)
{
   for (size_t ii = 0; ii < i; ++ii)
     for (size_t jj = 0; jj < j; ++jj)
       cout << data[ii][jj] << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    vector<vector<double>> data = {{0.0f, 1.0f}, {2.0f, 3.0f}};

    const size_t rows = data.size();
    const size_t cols = data[0].size();

    double** arrayData = new double*[rows];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
      arrayData[i] = &data[i][0];
    // ^ this obtains the address of first element of i-th row,
    //   where the vector data begins
    //   you can use arrayData[i] = data[i].data() if you have C++11 support

    foo(arrayData, rows, cols);

    delete [] arrayData;

    return 0;
}
```

I used dynamic allocation for it just because hardcoding the size may or may be not a good idea (depends on optimization requirements and such).

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

`copy(labelsVec.begin(), labelsVec.end(), labels);`

`labelsVec.begin()` returns a pointer to a `vector` type -- since your `labelsVec` is a `vector` of doubles -- and `labels` is a an array of type `double`: these types are not compatible. I suggest rethinking this implementation entirely, as it is odd to be copying a vector to an array except in specific instances (as stated above), and there are less convoluted solutions.

Comment: This makes me think that doing `copy(labelsVec[0].begin(), labelsVec[0].end(), labels);` should work, but I'm given the error that _double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000022000d0_

Comment: This is actually caused by another part of my program. (When I try and train my svm two more lines down)
`Ptr<ml::TrainData> tData = ml::TrainData::create(trainDataMat, ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
    svm->trainAuto(tData);`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
vector<vector<double>> labelsVec;
```

to

```
vector<double> labelsVec;
```

You are trying to insert an **array** of **doubles** into a **vector** of a **vector of doubles**.